# Make a css animation cross-browser

Tags: css, cross-browser, sass, css-transitions

I have the css animation which works only in Chrome. How can I make it cross-browser? Below is the code and the jsfiddle of it:

HTML:

```
<div class="main-nav">
    <a href="#">
        <div id="outer">
            <p>Hello!!!</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.main-nav {
    font-size: 250%;
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0 200px;
    text-shadow: 2px 1px 6px lighten(#141414, 50%);
    color: #141414;

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #outer {
        background:linear-gradient(to right, #1abc9c 50%, #444 50%);
        background-size:200% 100%;
        background-position:right bottom;
        font-size:64px;
        text-align:center;
        -webkit-background-clip:text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
        transition:all 1s;

        &:hover {
            background-position:left  bottom;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
    }
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yakovenkodenis/jq4rb3ox/3/
(It works correctly only in Chrome!)

Answer (score 1):

The `background-clip: text`property is only supported in webkit (safari and chrome), so there is no way for this to work in other browsers. You could try making an svg and animating the fill of that, although hopefully other browsers will adopt this someday.